# How to read User select Values of a static list of a SAS Prompt

Tags: static, sas, prompt

My Program has five files, every file has a macro. I have tried to make a stored process that has a prompt to ask the user which file to open (I have no rights to save the files in the database, where the SAS-Folders are).
The Prompt is called Prompt_1 and has five values of a static List  (1_First, 2_second, 3_third, 4_fourth, 5_fifth ).

In the Stored Process Manager > SAS Code Page > I have typed:

```
%if &Prompt_1= 1_First %then
%include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/1_ First.sas';
%else %if & Prompt_1= 2_second %then
%include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/2_ second.sas';
.....
```

The Error I get: The %IF statement is not valid in open code.

The Question is: How to read the value of Prompt_1 and compare it with “User select Values of a static list”?

P.S. Without IF Statement the program opens the file and excutes the Code
Thanks for help

Comment: Starting with SAS release 9.4M5 you can use %IF in open code, but not in the form you are using. You **must** enclose the statements to be run following the  the %THEN or %ELSE with a %DO/%END block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS up to version 9.4M4 disallows open-code %if statements.  The 9.4M5 documentation for %IF indicates updates to the SAS Foundation has removed the restriction.

There are many ways to process the prompt selection.

**Macro**

Write a macro that processes the selection in a conditional manner.  I recommend placing the `%include` inside a `%do` block to ensure the statements needed semi-colon is part of the conditional statement.

```
%macro process_selection;
  %if &Prompt_1 = 1_First %then %do;
    %include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/1_ First.sas';
  %end;
  %else
  %if & Prompt_1= 2_second %then %do;
    %include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/2_ second.sas';

  %end;
  %* etc …;
%mend;

%* invoke the macro;
%process_selection;
```

**DATA _ NULL _; CALL EXECUTE**

Data step can conditionally execute statements with `CALL EXECUTE`.  Best practice is to wrap the statement in `%NRSTR` to ensure it will execute after the DATA step completes.
You can also replace IF/THEN/ELSE with SELECT/WHEN statements.

```
data _null_;
  if "&prompt_1" = "1_First" then 
    call execute ( '%nrstr(%include "/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/1_ First.sas";)' );
  else
  if "&x" = "hello there2" then 
    call execute ( '%nrstr(%/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/2_ second.sas";)' );
run;
```

**MACRO 'associate array'**

For the case of the prompt selection value having no space or special characters, you can specify the potential target files in a series of macro variables.

```
%let FILE_1_First  = /home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/1_ First.sas;
%let FILE_2_Second = /home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/2_ Second.sas;

%include "%superq(FILE_&PROMPT_1)";
```

**Prompt dialog selection values**

You can change the prompt dialog to return the filename to include.  Either the fullpath

```
%include "&prompt_1";
```

or a partial part of the path (such as just the name part "1_ First")

```
%include "/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/&PROMPT_1..sas";
```

**%SYSFUNC(IFC**

A hackish way to conditionally process statements in open-code is to use `%sysfunc(ifc(…`
`IFC` is a function that evaluates an expression and returns one string for the true case, and a different (or no-string) for the false case. It won't hurt anything code or resource wise by having five of these statements in a row, wherein only one of the tests true.

```
%sysfunc(ifc(&Prompt_1 = 1_First
  , %include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/1_ First.sas';,));
%sysfunc(ifc(&Prompt_1 = 2_Second
  , %include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/2_ second.sas';,));
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, it worked with DATA _ NULL _; CALL EXECUTE
I appreciate your help

Comment: @mohammadhaddad - kindly choose this or Allen's response and [mark it as the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to your question

Answer (score 1):

Open code macro logic isn't available [until version 9.4m5](http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmmvacdc&cdcVersion=9.4&docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n18fij8dqsue9pn1lp8436e5mvb7.htm&locale=en).  One option for you now is to wrap it in a macro and call it:

```
%macro mymacro()
  %if &Prompt_1= 1_First %then %do;
    %include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/1_First.sas';
  %end;
  %else %if &Prompt_1= 2_second %then %do;
    %include '/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/2_second.sas';
  %end;
%mend;

%mymacro()
```

Another option (given that it appears as though your program names are identical to the prompt values) is to simply use the prompt macro value in the `%include` path:

```
%include "/home/admin/mohaddad/sasuser.v94/&prompt_1..sas";
```

Comment: Thank You, I appreciate your help!